# parse xml file and return list of specific variables

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm trying to extract a list of X,Y,Z from xml file. A part of xml is:

```
 <Data>
      <TargetPosition X="57.23471787820652" Y="-26.04271457691532" 
Z="9.988092935592704" Valid="1"/> #PosLang
      <StartPosition X="0" Y="0" Z="0" Valid="0"/>
    </Data>
  </Object>
  <Object Type="{aa99a9ec-4b85-442e-b914-de3579656eb5}">
    <ParentTObject Valid="1">
      <Translation X="0" Y="0" Z="0"/>
      <Rotation W="1" X="0" Y="0" Z="0"/>
    </ParentTObject>
    <Data>
      <TargetPosition X="58.81901290773406" Y="-20.09883392050945" 
Z="16.53197054898237" Valid="1"/> #NegLang
      <StartPosition X="0" Y="0" Z="0" Valid="0"/>
    </Data>
  </Object>
```

I need to extract X,Y,Z from all **TargetPosition** in file that have **#PosLang**
comment

```
def targets(path='some.xml'):
    try:
        e = ET.parse(path).getroot()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return list()

    Position = namedtuple('float', ['x', 'y', 'z'])

    for position in e.iter('TargetPosition'):
        yield Position(
            x=float(position.get('X')), 
            y=float(position.get('Y')),
            z=float(position.get('Z'))
        )
```

In y code i extract X,Y,Z of all TargetPosition, but i need only that have #PosLang comment

Comment: Don't confuse Python comments using `#` and XML comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your XML *really* contains the string `#PosLang` in exactly the way your sample shows, then that's not a comment, but a regular text node.

And since that text node follows the `<TargetPosition>` element, it will be in the `.tail` property:

```
def targets(path='some.xml'):
    try:
        e = ET.parse(path).getroot()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return list()

    Position = namedtuple('float', ['x', 'y', 'z'])

    for position in e.iter('TargetPosition'):
        if "#PosLang" in position.tail:
            yield Position(
                x=float(position.get('X')), 
                y=float(position.get('Y')),
                z=float(position.get('Z'))
            )
```

Comment: Exception appears:
 if "#PosLang" in position.tail:
                                  ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: You seem to be using tabs to indent your Python source code. Don't do that. The convention is that Python indentation is four spaces - update your editor's settings, make whitespace visible, fix the errors in your code indentation.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml), ElementTree ignores XML comments. Can you get the XML generated differently?

Comment: The problem is that it should be commented after generated. Because it should be marked as "negative" or "positive"

Comment: What is the criterion? When is a position "postive" and when is it "negative"?

Comment: Heuristicly, xml comes from neuronavigation system, it only produces points, without labeling them, if there was “language” response from person it will be positive, visa-versa